# Why do our .shx files disappear?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

We are using QGIS in our workgroup, and have recently updated to 1.8.0 Lisboa.
To share our file structure we are using [egnyte](http://www.egnyte.com/) similar to dropbox.
We all use Mac OS, and have used QGIS for years, and egnyte for several months now without any problems.

After updating to 1.8.0 we have experienced a frightening problem: The shx-files from a vast amount of our shape-folders are disappearing mysteriously, leaving the data useless. Fortunately we have been able to recover most of the shx-files from back ups, but obviously we can not rely on that for the future. The shx-files that disappear seem to be from folders we have recently worked with, but I'm not able to see any other tendencies in what is gone and what is still intact.